# ECEF elevation to LLH height

Tags: ecef

I have an ECEF position as:

```
x: 1776694.9644800487,
y: 5759463.252896432,
z: 2079310.7706825584
```

Using some online ECEF to LLH converters, this value is transformed to:

```
19.152548, 72.855909, 8.00
```

I am curious how is `2079310.7706825584` transformed to `8.00`.

Comment: I am more curious about the point of origin for those 2 coordinate systems. Formula would also help. So for same physical point on earth surface, one system has z value as 8 while other one has 2079310.7706825584. So the relationship between two coordinate systems would help a lot, and with some diagram would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ECEF is a Cartesian 3-D system, while LLH is a geodetic system. We refer to the Earth surface only to say that the reference ellipsoid is the best mathematical figure that adapts to it, but any point in the space can be represented in both systems.

From Richard H. Rapp, Geometric Geodesy, part I (1984):

[image: 1]

`Q'` is a point in the space, and `Q` is its proyection over the ellipsoid. The ellipsoidal height `h` is the distance between both points.

The origin of ellipsoidal heights is the ellipsoid surface, and the origin of geocentric Cartesian system is the center of the reference ellipsoid.

To calculate `h` we need to know the prime vertical radius of curvature at latitude `phi`, known as `v`:

`v = a /(1 – e^2 sin^2(phi))^0.5`

Where `a`and `e^2` are ellipsoid parameters semi-major axis and excentricity.

Then, `h = X sec(lambda) sec(phi) – v`, where `lambda` and `phi` must be calculated before than `h`.