# Transform height position from ECEF (EPSG:4978) to RH2000

Tags: coordinate-system, elevation, proj4js, ecef

I'm a novice regarding coordinate system and projections, and I'm trying to transform ECEF coordinates (projection adopted by Cesium) to the Sweref99 projection including the RH2000 height system (for example EPSG 5848). I'm using proj4js that recently received an update allowing geocentric conversions ([here](https://github.com/proj4js/proj4js/pull/327))

Doing the transformation extracts the correct northing and easting values, but the height value (what I was expecting to be in RH2000 format) is off by a couple of meters. I have seen this ([Q&A](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/353912/ecef-elevation-to-llh-height)), and it might not be the RH2000 height.

What is actually returned, and how would I (can I) use this information to transform to RH2000 format?

My case uses the following data:

```
- EPSG:4978: 3440988 914941 5274065
   transforms to
- EPSG:5848: 143171.919 6225798.530 8.581
```

The elevated value is expected to be ~4 (meters).

As I'm a novice regarding this and I have a very limited understanding of what proj4js is doing, neither practically or theoretically. I have a hard time understanding what is happening.

Comment: I don't know how to do it with proj4js, but it need to find the vertical shift grid SWEN17_RH2000.gtx to be able to transform the heights.

Comment: Thanks for the response. What I find is a way to calculate the geoid height for the RH2000. Please see the reference image: https://www.lantmateriet.se/globalassets/kartor-och-geografisk-information/gps-och-geodetisk-matning/geoidprofil1.gif
Basically, the GNSS-height (h) equals geoid height (N) + mean sea level
 (H). h = H + N
I do have the geoid height available. I would need the sea level calculated. So I would need either the GNSS or the sea level, I guess?

Comment: If you know the N value for that location, you can calculate H from h (h=8.851m). The vertical shift grid is a set of pairs location-N values. PROJ does perform some interpolation from the nearest locations to get the N value at that point, and then transform the ellipsoidal height to the orthometric one. But proj4js is not PROJ and may be does not support grid shifts.

Comment: You can also download the ASCII grid (https://www.lantmateriet.se/contentassets/493a548ae6c14631968c401dc08086c5/swen17_rh2000_dat.zip), transform from Cartesian to SWEREF 99 Geographic 3D, develop an interpolation from the grid to get N at that location, compute H based on the geographic 3D h value an the interpolated N one, and finally project from Geographic 2D to SWEN17, preserving H as third dimension. I'm sorry but I don't know how to do it with JS.

Comment: Thanks again for the extensive response. If I understand you right, 8.581 from my transformation represents the h of that location? The thing is that does not result in the expected height. If that is the case, then 8.581 = N + H. N in this case is 33.244 (you can control check here https://www.lantmateriet.se/zh-tw/self-service/geoidhojd/), which would mean that the mean sea level would be ~-25.3. And I expect it to be approximately 4 m. I may have misunderstood what you mean.

Comment: Regarding you other comment, this is what I already do. N is interpolated based on the SWEN17 RH2000 geoid grid. That is why I have access to the N height. The issue is that I need to extract the h (or directly calculate H somehow). Based your response you claim that h would be the result of the above calculation, but that does not seem to be the case? (check above control calculation)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110640/discussion-between-david-gustavsson-and-gabriel-de-luca).